# Converting objects to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please I will like to convert :

```
const words = {told: 64,
               mistake: 11,
               thought: 16,
               bad: 17}
```

TO

```
const words = [ 
  {text: 'told', value: 64,},
  {text: 'mistake', value: 11,},
  {text: 'thought', value: 16,},
  {text: 'bad', value: 17,
  },
]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Object entries and map

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` to loop over object's (keys & values):

```js
const data = {told: 64,
               mistake: 11,
               thought: 16,
               bad: 17
             };
const words = Object.entries(data).map(([text, value]) => ({text, value}));
console.log(words);
```